# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'toList' (Flutter Web) An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot

Tags: flutter, listview, web, provider

The error:
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'toList
comes, but code works when I use the commented provider i.e. final userdetails = Provider.of<List>(context).toList() ?? [];

However, if I use
final userdetails = Provider.of<List>(context).toList() ?? [];
I get this two errors, and app displays red screen.
1- NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'toList
2- An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List> listened by

```
import 'package:traveltogether_admin/Admin_Screens/Admin_ManageUsers_Tile.dart';
import 'package:traveltogether_admin/Models/user.dart';

class ManageUsers extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = 'Admin_manage_users';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userdetails = Provider.of<List<MyUserData>>(context).toList() ?? [];
    // final userdetails = Provider.of<List<RequestToJoinData>>(context).toList() ?? [];
    final user= userdetails;
    return ListView.builder(
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        // primary: false,
        itemCount: userdetails.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index)
    {
      print(userdetails);
          return ManageUserTile(user[index]);
    });
  }
}

//MyUserData is the model class.
// Rest of the code.
List<MyUserData> _MyUserDataListfromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot)
{
  return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
    return MyUserData(
      uid: uid ?? '',
      fullname: doc.data['fullname'] ?? '',
      CNIC: doc.data['CNIC'] ?? '',
      studentID: doc.data['studentID'] ?? '',
      department: doc.data['department'] ?? '',
      phonenumber: doc.data['phonenumber'] ?? '',
      vehicle: doc.data['vehicletype'] ?? '',
      VehicleCC: doc.data['vehicleCC'] ?? '',
      carModel: doc.data['carModel'] ?? '',
      numberplate: doc.data['numberplate'] ?? '',
    );
  }).toList();
}

Stream<List<MyUserData>> get myUserDataListStream{
    return myUserCollection.snapshots().map(_MyUserDataListfromSnapshot);
}
```

Comment: what type of data arr you expecting from `MyUserData`?

Comment: Please share more code, it's hard to interpret what is causing the problem.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Show me the code for provider.

Comment: Answered the question from my experience with firestore and flutter. Hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach a little bit.

```
final List<MyUserData> users = Provider.of<List<MyUserData>>(context);
```

Perform the null check in ListviewBuilder.

```
ListView.builder(
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        // primary: false,
        itemCount: userdetails?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
     
          return ManageUserTile(users[index]);
    });
```